# Laravel Passport for Authenticating Multiple Installations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking to recreate some internal systems using Laravel 5.3 as the internal systems need rebuilding. I am still fairly new to Laravel as we have used a bespoke framework based on PHP 4 for a few years, which is starting to show its' age.
The current setup makes use of having a users table for each application, which from my knowledge is not efficient as the userbase is shared (open to all employees).

Would I be right in thinking that I can set up a [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) application, with a database of users, and then use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) to make it an OAuth2 server? Say for example, passport.company.com and then new users are registered via this application.

Therefore, another two applications using Laravel i.e. CRM and CMS can then use the Passport system for authentication, rather than having to create users tables for each application?

If this is on the right lines, or there are better alternatives, I would be grateful to hear your feedback.

Thanks!

Edit: It appears that I'd need Laravel for all applications and not Lumen, after reading further into it.
I'm still curious as to know if I am on the right track however?

Comment: Do you have a working setup with passport? Can you tell us more about that?